# Segmentation fault (core dumped) if variable inside main?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

My code compiles and runs correctly unless i move the `int res[2000+1][2000+1];` inside main i get segmentation fault why does this strange behavior happens? Why does defining the variable locally cause a segmentation error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#define ll long long int
#define S(a) scanf("%d",&(a))
#define SL(a) scanf("%lld", &(a))
#define P(a) printf("%d",(a))
#define PL(a) printf("%lld",(a))
#define PTR(a) printf("%s",(a))
#define STR(a) scanf("%s",(a))
#define SP printf(" ")
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
using namespace std;
bool sort_pred(const pair<int,int>& left, const pair<int,int>& right)
    {
    return left.first < right.first;
    }
int res[2000+1][2000+1];
int main()
{
   int s,n;

     S(s);S(n);
vector <int> v (n+1);
vector <int> w(n+1);
  for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
   {
       cin>>w[i];
       cin>>v[i];
   }
  for(int i=0;i<=n;++i)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<=s;++j)
       {
           if(i==0 ||j==0)
           res[i][j]=0;
           else if(w[i-1]<=j)
               {
                res[i][j]=max(res[i-1][j-w[i-1]]+v[i-1],res[i-1][j]);
               }
               else
               res[i][j]=res[i-1][j];
           }
       }

   std::cout<<res[n][s];
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those macros are one day going to come back and bite you so hard you go home screaming. This is a fine example of macro abuse.

Comment: I use macros because i am using it in competitive programming but i will never ever use them in my programs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move it into main, it becomes a stack-based variable, and it's rather large (16M?) for the stack.  You could dynamically allocate it, using malloc, new, or using a std::vector.  At the top level of the file, it's a global variable, so is allocated when the process starts up.

Comment: Assuming the OP meant to tag it C++ only, `malloc` is a terrible suggestion. A `std::vector` would be way better.

Comment: Thanks a lot i thought all variables are stack based unless dynamically allocated so that's why i was wondering

Answer (score 2):

Consider the size of `int res[2000+1][2000+1]`. There will frequently not be enough space for an object that size on the stack, which is where it will appear if it is declared as a local variable.

Answer (score -1):

TO make things easier just declare

```
int res[2000];
```

it will be allocated.So the only pblm is size allocation has reached a saturation point for
your local variable.